# Angular Material dropdown width change

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-material, material-ui, material-design

I am using the Angular Material dropdown. It seems that the UL list element depends on button width. I have attached the button and dropdown. I want to change the drop-down width more than a button.
In the button I only type "Create" and in the dropdown, I want to type "Create Document", "Create PDF". Now I am getting button width size dropdown. so drop-down content not view properly. how change the drop-down width.

[image: Button width]

[image: drop down]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular Material already provides a solution for this.

`mat-select` provides one attribute called "panelClass"

Through which we can change width of dropdown panel like this:

In `style.css`:

```css
.panel-custom-width {
    width: 300px !important;
    max-width: unset !important;
}
```

In your component:

```html
<mat-select name="countryString" panelClass="panel-custom-width" [(value)]="selectedCountry">
    <mat-option [value]="'GB'">Great Britain</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="'US'">United States</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="'CA'">Canada</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```